# The user must be prompt to input the string and choose which characters to make replace

Tags: python, string, replace, strip

I need to prompt the user to input a string and I should prompt an input that will ask the user to input which characters to replace from the string.

```
string = input('Enter sentence: ')

string = string.replace(" ","")

print (string)
print ("\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [1677]: string = input('Enter sentence: ')                                                                                                                                                               
Enter sentence: I am James Bond 

In [1678]: replace_input = input("Enter chars to be replaced:")                                                                                                                                             
Enter chars to be replaced:a

In [1679]: string.replace(replace_input, ' ')                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1679]: 'I  m J mes Bond'
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to prompt the user to input a string. **You have this part done correctly.**

```
string = input('Enter sentence: ')
```

and I should prompt an input that will ask the user to input which characters to replace from the string. **I can't see where you asked for a second input.**

```
replace_input = input('Enter string to replace: ')
```

now you can continue with your code

```
string = string.replace(replace)input, "")
print(string + "\n")
```